# Converting vector layer to raster with cell size same as other raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, rasterization

I am a student and was taught by my professor in ArcMap but he wants us to repeat the process in QGIS. And i dont know how to set cell size in rasterize (vector to raster)in QGIS just like in ArcMap.

How can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: i only tried on using Rasterized and i dont know how to use it. Unlike in ArcMap, which allows me to define a cell size using another raster. And I am finding a way on how to define the cell size of the output file in QGIS just like in ArcMap.